# getElementById(x).value always undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

Ok, code first. Page code can be viewed at https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2628118/SMCH%20Portal%20-%20Home%20Page.htm and below is the JS I am trying to run.

```
 function checkClear(id){
        var place = document.getElementById(id);
        var gplace = document.getElementById(id+'check');
        var patt1=new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
        if(patt1.test(id.value)==true){
            gplace.innerHTML='<img src="img/gcheck.png" style="height:15px; width:auto;">';
            alert(id.value);
        }
        else{
            gplace.innerHTML='<img src="img/redx.png" style="height:15px; width:auto;">';
            alert(id.value);
        }
    }
```

I've double checked the DOM, I've tried doing form navigation, I'm not using JQuery, but I may add that into a later edition of what I'm building. I'd have to restructure everything I've already built in order to incorporate it, and I will do that, just not yet.

My problem: I can't seem to grab the value of the input forms. I keep getting undefined, and I can't run a good reg check on it to ensure it's only basic text. User-Error-Prevention, I'm just paranoid like that. I've been trying this one thing for hours. I know it's probably something simple. Help me please!!

Comment: What do you get when you do `alert(id)` inside `checkClear`?

Comment: id is a string, not an object; string's have no attribute `value`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the value of an id you can only get the value of an element with that id so instead of `id.value`, use `place.value`

Comment: Making that adjustment, I'm still getting regex errors. It's always something simple, missed semicolon, missed {}, something. Now if I could just get the regex, I'd get to move on to the harder stuff.... great...    nevermind.... Why must I be weening the coffee?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkClear(id){
    var place = document.getElementById(id); 
    var gplace = document.getElementById(id+'check'); 
    var patt1=new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    if(patt1.test(place.value)==true){
        gplace.innerHTML='<img src="img/gcheck.png" style="height:15px; width:auto;">';
        alert(place.value);
    }
    else{
        gplace.innerHTML='<img src="img/redx.png" style="height:15px; width:auto;">';
        alert(place.value);
    }
}
```

Comment: which would make it value.value in the resulting piece? that wouldn't work. look at the if clause. Also, my problem is that I was searching for id.value instead of place.value . Once it got pointed out to me, the rest clicked into place.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery libry, you can easily use this.

`if(place.value.match(^[a-zA-Z]+$)==true){`

otherwice you can create regex object and use it.

```
 function checkClear(id){
    var place = document.getElementById(id);
    var gplace = document.getElementById(id+'check');
    if(place.value.match(^[a-zA-Z]+$)==true){
        gplace.innerHTML='<img src="img/gcheck.png" style="height:15px; width:auto;">';
        alert(place.value);
    }
    else{
        gplace.innerHTML='<img src="img/redx.png" style="height:15px; width:auto;">';
        alert(place.value);
    }
}
```